# A marginal density function problem

Tags: calculus, probability, functions

Given a plane with three points, $(0,−1), (2,0)$, and $(0,1)$ with $x$-axis and $y$-axis connecting three points to make a triangle. Suppose this triangle represents the support for a joint continuous probability density Pick one of the following:

The marginal density $f(y)$, defined as $\int f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d}x$.

i) is an increasing function

ii) is a decreasing function

iii) is neither an increasing or decreasing function

iv) cannot be classified according to its increasing or decreasing character without more 
information.

Explain you choice

I pick (iii) when the marginal density function begins at $y=-1$, it must increase at some point before $y=1$ since the PDF has to be able to integrate to $1\ldots$ on the other than when it got to $y=1 \ldots$ it must decrease back to $0\ldots$so the marginal density function $f(y$) could not be increasing or decreasing function right $\ldots$ therefore, the answer would be neither increasing nor decreasing